# Can haskell grouping function be made similarly like that?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to somehow make group function similarly to that:

```
group :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
group [] = []
group (x:[]) = [[x]]
group (x:y:ys)
    | x == y = [[x,y], ys]
    | otherwise = [[x],[y], ys]
```

Result shoult be something like that:

```
group[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,1,1] ==> [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4],[1,1]]
```

PS: I already looked for Data.List implementation, but it doesn't help me much. (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/src/Data-List.html)

Is it possible to make group funtion more clearer than the Data.List implementation?

Or can somebody easily explain the Data.List implementation atleast?

Comment: Uhm, what exactly is wrong with `group` and `groupBy` from `Data.List` that makes it useless to you?

Comment: my guess: it's homework and the implementation is not *useless* it's probably hard to understand ... right?

Comment: Not homework, but hard to understand yes. @Carsten

Comment: Why don't you try to explain the `group` implementation to us, and see how far you can get, then we'll fill the rest in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is good, but I think you will need to define an ancillary function -- something like `group_loop` below -- to store the accumulated group. (A similar device is needed to define `span`, which the Data.List implementation uses; it is no more complicated to define `group` directly, as you wanted to do.) You are basically planning to move along the original list, adding items to the subgroup as long as they match, but starting a new subgroup when something doesn't match:

```
group [] = []
group (x:xs) = group_loop [x] x xs
  where
  group_loop acc c [] = [acc]
  group_loop acc c (y:ys) 
   | y == c    = group_loop (acc ++ [y]) c ys
   | otherwise = acc : group_loop [y] y ys
```

It might be better to accumulate the subgroups by prepending the new element, and then reversing all at once:

```
group [] = []
group (x:xs) = group_loop [x] x xs
  where
  group_loop acc c [] = [reverse acc]
  group_loop acc c (y:ys) 
   | y == c    = group_loop (y:acc) c ys
   | otherwise = reverse acc : group_loop [y] y ys
```

since then you don't have to keep retraversing the accumulated subgroup to tack things on the end. Either way, I get

```
 >>> group[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,1,1] 
 [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4],[1,1]]
```

Comment: Ty. Very nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

`group` from `Data.List` is a specialized version of `groupBy` which uses the equality operator `==` as the function by which it groups elements.

The `groupBy` function is defined like this:

```haskell
groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy _  []           =  []
groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
                           where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
```

It relies on another function call `span` which splits a list into a tuple of two lists based on a function applied to each element of the list. The [documentation for `span`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:span) includes this note which may help understand its utility.

> `span p xs` is equivalent to `(takeWhile p xs, dropWhile p xs)`

Make sure you first understand `span`. Play around with it a little in the REPL.

Ok, so now back to `groupBy`. It uses `span` to split up a list, using the comparison function you pass in. That function is in `eq`, and in the case of the `group` function, it is `==`. In this case, the `span` function splits the list into two lists: The first of which matches the first element pulled from the list, and the remainder in the second element of the tuple.

And since `groupBy` recursively calls itself, it appends the rest of the results from `span` down the line until it reaches the end.

Visually, you can think of the values produced by `span` looking something like this:

```haskell
([1], [2,2,3,3,3,4,1,1])
([2,2], [3,3,3,4,1,1])
([3,3,3], [4,1,1])
([4], [1,1])
([1,1], [])
```

The recursive portion joins all the first elements of those lists together in another list, giving you the result of

```haskell
[[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4],[1,1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at this is to take the first element `x` of the input and recursively group the rest of it. `x` will then either be prepended to the first element of the grouping, or go in a new first group by itself. Some examples:

1. With `[1,2,3]`, we'll add 1 to a new group in `[[2], [3]]`, yielding `[[1], [2], [3]]`
2. With `[1,1,2]`, we'll add the first 1 to the first group of `[[1], [2]]`, yielding `[[1,1], [2]]`.

The resulting code:

```
group :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
group [] = []
group [x] = [[x]]
group (x:y:ys) = let (first:rest) = group (y:ys)
                 in if x /= y
                    then [x]:first:rest -- Example 1 above
                    else (x:first):rest -- Example 2 above
```

IMO, this simplifies the recursive case greatly by treating singleton lists explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I come up with a solution with `foldr`:

```
helper x [] = [[x]]
helper x xall@(xs:xss) 
   | x == head xs = (x:xs):xss
   | otherwise = [x]:xall

group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
group = foldr helper []
```